# Unknown Encoding Error in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, character-encoding

I am new to Node.js and stuck on an error which is irritating me from 2 days!

The JS looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
 console.log("A request was made of url : " + req.url);
 res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
 var data = fs.createReadStream(__dirname, '/index.html', 'utf8');
 data.pipe(res);
});
server.listen(4242);
console.log("Server is running.....");
```

And this is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE <html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Index Website</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Some HTML</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

But I end up getting this error:

```
string_decoder.js:13
throw new Error(`Unknown encoding: ${enc}`);
^

Error: Unknown encoding: /index.html
at normalizeEncoding (string_decoder.js:13:11)
at new StringDecoder (string_decoder.js:22:19)
at new ReadableState (_stream_readable.js:99:20)
at ReadStream.Readable (_stream_readable.js:108:25)
at new ReadStream (fs.js:1907:12)
at Object.fs.createReadStream (fs.js:1885:10)
at Server.<anonymous> (G:\Docs\Node.js\server.js:7:19)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:546:12)
```

Can someone tell me what went wrong, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: You seem to use [`fs.createReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) incorrectly.

Comment: Can you explain the mistake please ?

Comment: `fs.createReadStream` takes parameters `fs.createReadStream(path[, options])` so for your case you should write it like `fs.createReadStream(\`${__dirname}/index.html\`, {encoding: 'utf8'})`

Comment: Thank You so much Sir !
That solved my problem and I am feeling so much relaxed now :)

Comment: I will put a comment with this answer. Please mark it correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Giving encoding error in nodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483055/giving-encoding-error-in-nodejs)

Comment: @Pranshu Please [avoid expletives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233) in your posts, especially in cases like this where it's totally unnecessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fs.createReadStream` takes parameters

```
fs.createReadStream(path[, options])
```

so for your case you should write it like

```
fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/index.html`, {encoding: 'utf8'})
```

Answer (score 0):

for the use __dirname you should;

first join the path

```
const indexPath = path.join(___dirname, "index.html");
```

then

```
const data = fs.createReadStream(indexPath, 'utf8');
```